# How do I fish so my family won't starve?

Tags: the-oregon-trail-40th-anniversary

I was trying to read the instructions on how to fish, but my hand shook and instead of clicking the down arrow to read more, I closed the explanation. I tried just fishing anyhow, hoping I would figure it out, but nothing worked. I get nibbles on my line but I can't actually figure out how to reel the fish in!

How can I fish? I dont want my family  to starve!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fishing tip reads:

> Up ahead is a spot to fish. Use the Wii Remote to aim and press the <kbd>B</kbd>
>   Button to cast. Cast your bobber where fish will see the bait, but not
>   so close that you will spook them.  Fish will nibble the bait, but
>   wait until they bite and pull the bobber under water before you start
>   to reel in. Rotate the Control Stick to reel in.

In my experience the fish always pull the bobber down after 1-3 nibbles. Don't try to reel the fish in as fast as you can. Maintain a steady pace as you spin the control stick and you'll have you're "Reel Talent" trophy in no time.

Comment: Awesome. I was missing the bit on how to reel fish in. :)